# Remove the latest created document from the mongoose collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am currently using but it removes all documents with the same name.

```
Reservation.remove({name:req.body.name}, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: How do you identify the latest document ? do you have a timestamp field that you use ? if yes you can use something like `db.collection.findOneAndDelete(
   {name:"some name"},
   { sort : { "ts" : -1 } }
)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In newer mongodb versions (3.2+) there's a [`findOneAndDelete`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/#db-collection-findoneanddelete) method, so in mongoshell you could call:

```
db.collection.findOneAndDelete({}, {sort: {_id: -1}})
```

this would work if you use mongodb ids, which have a timestamp 'baked-in'. Otherwise you'd need some other time field to sort on.

You can also use [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndRemove) approach with Mongoose (from your post I cannot tell for sure which mongodb client you're using).